# Hover div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

Here is my script :

```
  <body>
    <div id ="mainCategory" class='fade'>
        Category</div>
    <div id="divSubCategory">
        Category1
        <br />
        Category2
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("div").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).append($("#divSubCategory").html());
            },
            function () {
                $("#divSubCategory").remove();
            }
         );
        $("#divSubCategory.fade").hover(function () { $(this).fadeOut(100); $(this).fadeIn(500); });

    </script>
</body>
```

I want to show and hide divSubCategory on mainCategory hover. But it doesn't work. What should I add?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainCategory').bind('mouseenter', function() {
        $('#divSubCategory').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#mainCategory').bind('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#divSubCategory').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: It works but I want to hide sub category when the mouse leaving from main category. This hides sub category while mouse on main category.

Comment: The problem with this is that `div#divSubCategory` is not enclosed in `div#mainCategory` and therefore when you try to put your mouse over `div#divSubCategory` that div will hide. If this is for a menu system (for instance) then this will not work for you, because you need `div#divSubCategory` to display while you mouse over it too.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about those :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok dude the problem is that you're using `.html()`. This copies the inner html (not the outer `<div id="divSubCategory"></div>` bit too... just the bit in the middle.

Because of this, when you do `$('#divSubCategory').remove()` its removing the actual div in the HTML, not the HTML you've moved into the div above.

Assuming you have `display: none` on `#divSubCategory` you will see the text from that div get appended to the first div, then when you mouse-out it will not go away (although the second (hidden) div will get deleted).

Anyway the way around this is to use `clone()`. I'll do a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/fZZu5/1/

I also fixed your fades for you.

EDIT: This moves the `div#divSubCategory` into the `div#mainCategory` before showing it and then removes it completely from there when you mouse-out - this is what I assumed you wanted to do from your code. Nicks just shows and hides it where it is. Depending on what you want, both these answers are correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the 100% working with your requirement:

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWqnk/8/

Answer (score -3):

Wrap your code inside the document.ready() function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem as the code is written after the HTML.

Comment: @ThomasClayson, I have html tags just didn't coppy to here.

Comment: @cagin yeah, I figured, but what I meant is that you don't need to use `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` (or that its not your problem here) because the javascript comes AFTER your HTML. So the HTML gets to the browser before the script, and all is fine. However you probably should use `$(document).ready()` incase you want to move your scripts into an external file or something isn't working properly.